# Multiplication in Tower Field $GF(2^4)^2$

Tags: aes, implementation, finite-field

I'm currently reading an article which deals with "Squeezing Polynomial Masking into Tower Fields " for performing an efficient multiplication of elements in $GF(2^8)$.
Thereby it is explained that one first hast to do an affine transformation on the elements in $GF(2^8)$ and apply the actual multiplication in the tower field $GF(2^4)^2$. The paper defines an overall algorithm to perform the multiplication in the smaller field according to:

**Multiplication:** The multiplication $c = ab$ of two elements $a,b \in GF(2^8)$ can be computed in $GF(2^8)$ as:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
c_h = &(b_h + b_l) (a_h + a_l) + b_l a_l\\
c_l  \ = &b_ha_h\gamma +b_l a_l
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

where

- $a \mapsto \phi(a_h, a_l)$,
- $b \mapsto \phi(b_h, b_l)$,
- $(c_h,c_l) \mapsto \phi^{-1}(c_h, c_l)$

and all operations defined in $GF(2^4)$.
Apparently $\phi$ denotes the isomorphic mapping, which bijectively maps the elements from $GF(2^8)$ to $GF(2^4)^2$.
In the follwoing it is also stated that the generator polynomial is given according to $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}[y]/(y^2 + y + \gamma)$.

Consequently, I started to tabulate the required multiplications in the smaller field which yield the following code

```
for(uint8_t i = 0; i <= 0xF; i++)
{
    for(uint8_t j = 0; j <= 0xF; j++)
    {
        uint8_t result = gf_2_4_multiply(i, j);
        gf_2_4_table[i][j] = result;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, now I fail to understand how the decomposition into the smaller field has to be done. Thereby, I encountered a post from [intuition-behind-mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739707/what-is-the-intuition-behind-mapping-of-elements-from-gf28-to-gf222#3756361) which I do not really understand. In particular I do not understand how the mapping matrix must be applied to perform the transformation into the smaller subfileds. Additional to that, I do not understand the meanig of $\gamma$ in this context. For that reason, I would be gradeful if anyone could give me a few hints or explain how the overall multiplication/mapping to the smaller field works.

Best regards

ratbaldmeyer

Comment: section J. in my work here: https://github.com/bpdegnan/aes/blob/master/aes-sbox/documentation/aessbox.pdf